# Double-escaping XML entities

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have an XML snippet, say:

```
<root>
  <node>This &amp; that</node>
</root>
```

This needs to be sent over SOAP as a string, our framework escapes it as:

```
&lt;root>&lt;node>This &amp;amp; that&lt;/node>&lt;/root>
```

An end-user tells us this doesn't parse, and our unit test (correctly) unescapes it.  The resultant XML snippet should be conformant - `&lt;node>This &amp;amp; that&lt;/node>` from transmission should result in `<node>This &amp; that</node>` to send to a rendering layer when unescaped, right?

Comment: Whyn't add this data in CDATA tag, if you have control in constructing XML?

Comment: +1 agree.  Wasn't my decision.  Anyway, to serialize CDATA I would have had to escape `&gt;` and if `&amp;gt;` didn't parse we'd be in the same boat.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to escape anything if it is included in CDATA. I may be wrong too.

Comment: ^edited.  The trailing `>` on a CDATA tag needs to be escaped.  That's outside the CDATA tag itself, btw.

Comment: If you are using JAX-WS, the following post demonstrates how this can be done with JAXB:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis appears correct. From the available evidence, I would conclude that your end-user's software is not correctly handling the data, such as by extracting XML text (un-unescaped, if you see what I mean) from the SOAP message (rather than the text content of the document) and attempting to parse that, or using something other than an XML parser at some stage.

Perhaps you could make sure your and their systems correctly process e.g. plain text such as `In order to write a literal "&" in XML, HTML, or SGML text one writes "&amp;" instead`.

(I am mildly concerned by your description of a unit test as "doubly-unescaping" the text, as this suggests dangerous ways of thinking about the problem. If you "unescape" the string `&lt;root>&lt;node>This &amp;amp; that&lt;/node>&lt;/root>` twice, the result is either an error or the string `<root><node>This & that</node></root>` which is neither well-formed XML nor anything else you should likely want.)

Comment: >(I am mildly concerned...)

Right on, I guess that could be misinterpreted.  The unit test itself doesn't doubly-unescape it, it unescapes the incoming string resulting in conformant XML (with `&amp;`) to pass on to a rendering layer.  Thanks for the shot of confidence.. I haven't done much with SOAP, and I think the String-based interface is kind of weak using a framework that supports a much richer interchange using XML but we gots what we gots... :(

Comment: @Chris My concern is entirely alleviated. Good luck!